# How can i pass multiple values to a function like we do in concat()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

here are two arrays from my code written below .
i have wrote a function to add their elements but i want to make something that can take any number of arrays and join them accordingly!

array 1:

```
var product =
[ [ 'Product Code' ],
[ 'AFC' ],
[ 'MFC' ],
[ 'AC' ],
[ 'MC' ],
[ 'AT' ],
[ 'MT' ],
[ 'AD' ],
[ 'MTB' ],
[ 'HBB' ] ]
```

array 2:

```
var quantity = 
[ [ 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL' ],
[ 16, 17, 6, 0 ],
[ 4, 2, 0, 0 ],
[ 2, 11, 0, 0 ],
[ 2, 6, 2, 0 ],
[ 6, 17, 1, 0 ],
[ 0, 2, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] ]
```

var final = msJoin(product,qty);

```
final = 
[ [ 'Product Code', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL' ],
  [ 'AFC', 16, 17, 6, 0 ],
  [ 'MFC', 4, 2, 0, 0 ],
  [ 'AC', 2, 11, 0, 0 ],
  [ 'MC', 2, 6, 2, 0 ],
  [ 'AT', 6, 17, 1, 0 ],
  [ 'MT', 0, 2, 0, 0 ],
  [ 'AD', 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 'MTB', 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  [ 'HBB', 0, 0, 1, 0 ] ]
```

with the code below:

```
function msJoin(array1,array2){

  var concatArray = (array1,array2)=>{
    
    var final = [];

    for(var i = 0 ; i<array1.length;i++){
      
      var tempElement = [];

      array1[i].forEach(
      
        function (ee){
          tempElement.push(ee);
          console.log(ee);
        }
      );
      array2[i].forEach(
      
        function (ee){
          tempElement.push(ee);
          console.log(ee);
        }
      );
      
      final.push(tempElement);
    }

    return final;
  }

  return concatArray(array1,array2);
}
```

how can I write it for dynamic numbers of arrays ?

ms(array1,array2,array3..........);

Comment: Are the lengths of the arrays always the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `reduce` and `map` to get the result you want.

```js
function joinArray(...arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a.map((e, i) => [...e, ...b[i]]));
}

var product = [
  ["Product Code"],
  ["AFC"],
  ["MFC"],
  ["AC"],
  ["MC"],
  ["AT"],
  ["MT"],
  ["AD"],
  ["MTB"],
  ["HBB"],
];

var quantity = [
  ["S", "M", "L", "XL"],
  [16, 17, 6, 0],
  [4, 2, 0, 0],
  [2, 11, 0, 0],
  [2, 6, 2, 0],
  [6, 17, 1, 0],
  [0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0],
];

var brand = [
  ["Sasdf"],
  ["asdg"],
  ["223"],
  ["asdf"],
  ["gasdf"],
  ["asdfa"],
  ["232"],
  ["gasdf"],
  ["asdf"],
  ["323"],
];

const output = joinArray(product, quantity, brand);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use forEach to add elements in a single array from any number of arrays.

You can also use

```
  result[j] = [...result[j], ...val];
```

```js
var product = [
  ["Product Code"],
  ["AFC"],
  ["MFC"],
  ["AC"],
  ["MC"],
  ["AT"],
  ["MT"],
  ["AD"],
  ["MTB"],
  ["HBB"],
];

var second = [
  ["temp"],
  ["temp"],
  ["temp"],
  ["temp"],
  ["temp"],
  ["temp"],
  ["temp"],
  ["temp"],
  ["temp"],
  ["temp"],
];

var quantity = [
  ["S", "M", "L", "XL"],
  [16, 17, 6, 0],
  [4, 2, 0, 0],
  [2, 11, 0, 0],
  [2, 6, 2, 0],
  [6, 17, 1, 0],
  [0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0],
];

function join(...arrs) {
  const result = Array(arrs[0].length).fill([]);

  arrs.forEach((arr, i) => {
    arr.forEach((val, j) => {
      result[j] = result[j].concat(val);
    });
  });

  return result;
}
console.log(join(product, second, quantity));
```

Comment: woow!! That's great! but could you explain ... (these three dots) as a parameter or you can share an article ! That would be so great of you.

Comment: This is spread syntax, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [Javascript.info](https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread)

Comment: You can also use `result[j] = [...result[j], ...val];`. It will give you the same result

Comment: got it ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

```js
function add() {
  let a = 0
  Object.keys(arguments).forEach(ckey => {
    a = a + arguments[ckey]
  })

  console.log(a)
}

add(1)

add(1, 4, 21, 123, 1)
```

Comment: This is not the answer at all. It is adding the numbers...

Comment: Thanks for this example. It'll help me in my codes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lodash imported,

```js
import {zip, join} from 'lodash';

const product =
[ [ 'Product Code' ],
[ 'AFC' ],
[ 'MFC' ],
[ 'AC' ],
[ 'MC' ],
[ 'AT' ],
[ 'MT' ],
[ 'AD' ],
[ 'MTB' ],
[ 'HBB' ] ];

const quantity = 
[ [ 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL' ],
[ 16, 17, 6, 0 ],
[ 4, 2, 0, 0 ],
[ 2, 11, 0, 0 ],
[ 2, 6, 2, 0 ],
[ 6, 17, 1, 0 ],
[ 0, 2, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 1, 0 ] ];

const result = zip(product, quantity).map(e => [join(e)]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am using google apps script and it is using the old version of javascript. There is no direct way to use npm modules in it (still possible)!